# Distribution of maximum of correlated Gaussians

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, order-statistics

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be iid standard Gaussian random variables.

Consider the set of random variables $M =\left\{\left( X_i-X_j\right) :i,j = \left\{1,2,\dots,n\right\} \& i\ne j\right\}$.

I am trying to find a closed form expression for the cdf or an analytical expression on the upper bound of the cdf of the maximum of $M$. How do I take care of the correlation between the variables in $M$? Is there any asymptotic results as $n \rightarrow \infty$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
If you are interested only in distribution of maximum of the differences than notice 
$$ 
\max_{i,j=1,\ldots,n ~ \& ~i\ne j} \left\{\left( X_i-X_j\right) \right\}
= \max_{i=1,\ldots,n}\left\{X_i\right\} - \min_{{i=1,\ldots,n}}\left\{X_i\right\}.
$$
So all you have to do is find a joint distribution of minimal and maximal value of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$.

Comment: Well, there is more to it than that. After finding the joint pdf of the $1^{st}$ and $n^{th}$ order statistics, one then needs to find the distribution of the sample range. The latter is the tricky part.